# NodeJS + Electron - Optimizing Displaying Large Files

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to read large files. Currently, I'm following the NodeJS documentation on how to read the large files but when I read a somewhat large file (~1.1 MB, ~20k lines), my Electron app freezes up for about 6 minutes and then the app finishes loading all the lines.

Here's my current code

```
var fileContents = document.getElementById("fileContents")
        //first clear out the existing text
        fileContents.innerHTML = ""
        if(fs.existsSync(pathToFile)){
            const fileLine = readline.createInterface({
                input: fs.createReadStream(pathToFile)
            })

            fileLine.on('line', (line) => {
                fileContents.innerHTML += line + "\n"
            })


       } else {
            fileContents.innerHTML += fileNotFound + "\n"
            console.log('Could not find file!!')
       }
```

And the tag I'm targeting is a `<xmp>` tag.

What are some ways that people have displayed large files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams can often be useful for high performance as they allow you to process one line at a time without loading the whole file into memory.

In this case however, you are loading each line and then concatenating onto your existing string (`fileContents.innerHTML`) with `+=`. All that concatenating is likely to be slower than just loading the whole contents of the file as one string. Worse still, you are outputting HTML every time you read in a line. So with 20k lines you are asking the rendering engine to render HTML 20,000 times!

Instead, try reading in the file as one string, and outputting the HTML just once.

```
fs.readFile(pathToFile, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  fileContents.innerHTML = data;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation behind what I'm doing wrong! I tested it out and the file just displays in a matter of seconds rather than minutes!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with fs.readFile() is that you just won't be able to open large files, for instance 600Mb, you need to use stream anyway for very big files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a genomics app called AminoSee using Node and Electron. When I started trying to ingest bigger than 2 GB files I had to switch to streaming architecture as my program was trying to *load the entire file into memory*. Since I scan the file this is clearly ludicrous. Here is the core of my processor, from CLI app at:

sourced: https://github.com/tomachinz/AminoSee/blob/master/aminosee-cli.js

```
  try {
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(es.split()).pipe(es.mapSync(function(line){
      readStream.pause(); // curious to test performance of removing
      streamLineNr++;
      processLine(line); // process line here and call readStream.resume() when ready
      readStream.resume();
    })
    .on('error', function(err){
      error('While reading file: ' + filename, err.reason);
      error(err)
    })
    .on('end', function() {
      log("Stream ending");
    })
    .on('close', function() {
      log("Stream closed");
      setImmediate( () => { // after a 2 GB file give the CPU 1 cycle breather!
        calcUpdate() ;
        saveDocuments();
      });
    }));
  } catch(e) {
    error("ERROR:"  + e)
  }
```

I used setImmediate a lot as my program would get quite far ahead of itself before I learnt about callbacks and promises! Was a great time to learn about race conditions that for sure. Still has a million bugs would make a good learning project.